# Instantiate View Controller with Identifier with custom init

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, instantiation

How would I go about instantiating a custom `ViewController` class with custom `init` by using the storyboard method?

How would calling the `ProfileViewController(userId: "abc")` init?

**Instantiate View Controller**

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as UIViewController
```

**Custom View Controller class**

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

var userId = ""

init(userId: String) {
    self.userId = userId
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let menuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "MenuIcon"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "menuBarButtonItemClicked")
    menuItem.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is not possible.
However you can do something like this

```
let destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as ProfileViewController
destViewController.userId = "abc"
```

Comment: Thought it wasn't going to be possible. Thanks for the answer!